# How to get the absolute path of the current javascript file name

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript file named `main.js`.

Inside `main.js` I want to get the absolute path of this current file, something like:

```
http://server/app/main.js

http://server/app/script/main.js
```

What is the fastest way to get the absolute path?

Comment: This similar question has more accurate and complete answers https://stackoverflow.com/q/403967/1480391

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can investigate script collection at:

```
var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName("script");
```

For each element in the returned `scripts` array you can access its `src` attribute.

The currently executing include file will always be the last one in the `scripts` array.  So you can access it at `scripts[scripts.length-1]`.

Of course this will only work at time of initial code run and would not be useful for example within a function that is called after initial script is loaded, so if you need the value available later, you would need to save it to a variable.

Comment: Will it work if we have included multiple files... then how will each js file show it's own src path.. ??

Comment: Worth noting that you might want to use another means of getting the script you want out of the `scripts` array.  I use this method, but am having reports that every so often in Firefox (blegh...) there's another script that's been loaded by the time my logic grabs that array of elements.

The smart thing to do would be to grab like the last 3 or so and loop through them and find the one with the filename you're looking for.

Answer (score 25):

**Get the current pathname of the javascript file**

Put this in your apache directory underneath /tmp and call it test.html.  Visit the url

```
localhost/grader/test.html?blah=2#foobar
```

Javascript:

```
<html>
<script>
  alert(location.pathname);  // /tmp/test.html
  alert(location.hostname);  // localhost
  alert(location.search);    // ?blah=2
  alert(document.URL);       // http://localhost/tmp/test.html?blah=2#foobar
  alert(location.href);      // http://localhost/tmp/test.html?blah=2#foobar
  alert(location.protocol);  // http:
  alert(location.host);      // localhost
  alert(location.origin);    // http://localhost
  alert(location.hash);      // #foobar
</script>                            
</html>
```

More information on attributes of location: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_location.asp

**Or if you have jquery:**

```
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
  $(location).attr('href');      // http://localhost/tmp/test.html?blah=2#foobar
  $(location).attr('pathname');  // /tmp/test.html
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

This will work. However, it requires that you already know what the filename of the script is. But in most situations you would know that.

```
function absFileLoc(filename) {
  var scriptElements = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
  for (var i = 0; i < scriptElements.length; i++) {
    var source = scriptElements[i].src;
    if (source.indexOf(filename) > -1) {
      var location = source.substring(0, source.indexOf(filename)) + filename;
      return location;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Here is the function along with one that gets the absolute location of css files .  https://gist.github.com/jamrizzi/44bac4240057b4a89a2d918d05680e3d

Answer (score 2):

### Modern way

The fastest way to get the absolute path is to use [document.currentScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.currentScript)

```js
const url = document.currentScript.src;
```

Also to read components of a url you can use [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) :)

```js
const url = new URL('http://www.example.com/cats');
console.log(url.hostname); // "www.example.com"
console.log(url.pathname); // "/cats"
```

All modern browsers should support these methods.

Answer (score 1):

```
var path = document.location.pathname
```

will provide the current html page.

if you look for the current script, try the way mentioned in this site:

http://bencarpenter.co.uk/javascript-path-to-the-current-script

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an older question, but still actual because IE still not provides the script src.

The best form me was to give the script tag an unique id:

```
    <script id="kuvaScript" src="jscripts/kuva/kuva.min.js"></script>
```

Inside the script i use:

```
    var thisScript = $("#kuvaScript").attr("src");
    var thisPath = thisScript.split('/').slice(0, -1).join('/')+'/';
```

It will keep the src format as it is (relative or complete) and was tested in IE and Chrome.

Hope it will save you a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

## Very easy

Put this in the *.js file you want to get path:

```
let scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script')
let lastScript = scripts[scripts.length -1]
console.log('lastScript', lastScript.src)
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this if you want to get the current file name or directory

```js
location.href.split('/')[ location.href.split('/').length - 1 ];
```

Comment: location.href gets the url of the current web page, not the currently executing javascript file.

Comment: we first get the url, than split it to get the desired part.
location.href.split('/')[ 0 ]; //gets the first part
location.href.split('/')[ location.href.split('/').length - 1 ]; //gets the  file name

Comment: No, that's incorrect. You're getting the url of the page, not the current javascript file. If you put that javascript code into a file www.abc.com/file.js which is included in www.def.com/page.html, location.href will return www.def.com/page.html. The question is asking how to get the name of the javascript file, i.e. www.abc.com/file.js.

Comment: Did you tried my code in the console window?? For me it worked fine!

Comment: Yes, I tried, and it gives the .html rather than .js location. Try yourself and you'll see!