# Is there any way to set baseurl dynamicly in require.js?

Tags: javascript, zend-framework2, requirejs

I am building an application on [Pi-engine](https://github.com/pi-engine/pi) (a php application engine based on zend framework 2).

In my application the javascript file path depends on the application name, while the application name is
pickded by installer.

For example the url of require.js would be:

`http://my.site.name/asset/module-{module_name}/script/js/require.js`

module_name changes according to what name the application is given.

I know I can put path in 'data-main' attribute in backend like:

```
<script data-main="/asset/module-{module_name}/script/" src="/asset/module-{module_name}/script/js/require.js"></script>
```

But I want to know is there any way to set baseurl dynamicly using javascript so that I don't need to touch the backend.

Answer (score 10):

http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config

*Also, you can define the config object as the global variable require before require.js is loaded, and have the values applied automatically. This example specifies some dependencies to load as soon as require.js defines require():*

```
<script>
    var require = {
        baseUrl: generateBaseUrl()
    };
</script>
<script src="scripts/require.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly you can use 'baseUrl' in the config object where you can set the path where the js files are found.

```
require.config({
   baseUrl: "/js/"
});
```

Comment: If I use `baseUrl: "/js/"`, the request path become `http://my.site.name/js/target.js`.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for answering, I just found a solution using javascript on page: [how to get the absolute path of the current javascript file name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13261970/how-to-get-the-absolute-path-of-the-current-javascript-file-name)

```
var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName("script");

require.config({
    baseUrl: '/asset' + scripts[scripts.length-1].src.match(/\/module.*?\//)[0] + 'script/',
});
```

It seems strange but it works.

Answer (score 0):

In order to avoid pollution of the global scope, you can wrap dynamic config code as in your case in an immediately executing function:

```
require.config((function(){
    var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName("script");
    return {
        baseUrl: '/asset' + scripts[scripts.length-1].src.match(/\/module.*?\//)[0]
    };
})());
```