# Is there a way to get the path or the name of js file inside it?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get the path of the js file to realize the version number. There's a way to do that?

Comment: and where?? in HTML file, add more details

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the absolute path of the current javascript file name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13261970/how-to-get-the-absolute-path-of-the-current-javascript-file-name)

Comment: Do you have a example or something for us to work with that will enable us to help you / answer your question? With no example = no solid answer.

Comment: Thanks everyone.
Can't get the script from the html. We use a generic url  (.../getJs) which redirects to different js files, according to different statuses. I'm trying to dynamically understand which js file I was redirected to.

Answer (score 0):

You can add class or id to the `<script>` tag and retrieve its `src` attribute.

```
<script id="script" src="path/to/file.js">
<script>
    document.getElementById('script').src
</script>
```

Comment: This isn't worth posts as an answer without explaining how you would get the src attribute from a class name. Why not an ID? And what's wrong with `getElementsByTagName('script');` ...

Comment: I was just going to edit it to id or class :) and of course you can use any way to query DOM.

Comment: I think an example of your method would make your answer more useful.

Comment: Thanks everyone.
Can't get the script from the html. We use a generic url  (.../getJs) which redirects to different js files, according to different statuses. I'm trying to dynamically understand which js file I was redirected to.