# How can a javascript get its own absolute path on my computer?

Tags: javascript, instruments, xcode-instruments

When using a javascipt to UIAutomation Test in Instruments, is there any chance the javascript can get it's own absolute path on my computer? Like in a shell script, we can use `pwd` to get its absolute path.

Comment: May I know what you want to do with the absolute path?

Comment: @DattatreyaKugve , According to "UI Automation JavaScript Reference for iOS", Apple has offered a interface called "performTaskWithPathArgumentsTimeout(path, args, timeout)" to execute a task, it can be used like this "host.performTaskWithPathArgumentsTimeout("/bin/echo", ["Hello World"], 5)". Here the "path" must be an absolute path, and I need javascript's absolute path. I hope instead of manually specifying it, I can get it automatically. In this way, everyone using this javascript on their own computer can just using it without altering anything.

Comment: Just to understand more  'host.performTaskWithPathArgumentsTimeout'  Is it a javascript function? If it is a javascript where it is deployed? On a application server?

Comment: @DattatreyaKugve, Yeah, the javascript can be imported in the Instruments which is a testing tool. And the Instruments can run it. [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/UIAutomation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004652-CH78-SW1)

Comment: Ok . I don't know about inner workings of this instrument tool. But I don't think javascript can get it's absolute system path. Generally javascript gets deployed on a web server  as part of  a application and it will be having a absolute path with respect to the 'context-name' of the application. You can get the absolute path with respect to 'context-name' as mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13261970/how-to-get-the-absolute-path-of-the-current-javascript-file-name)