# How to get actual windows path using javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to find actual path of my working directory using javascript. I read from this post 
[How to get the absolute path of the current javascript file name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13261970/how-to-get-the-absolute-path-of-the-current-javascript-file-name)

```
<script>
  alert(location.pathname);  // /tmp/test.html
  alert(location.hostname);  // localhost
  alert(location.search);    // ?blah=2
  alert(document.URL);       // http://localhost/tmp/test.html?blah=2#foobar
  alert(location.href);      // http://localhost/tmp/test.html?blah=2#foobar
  alert(location.protocol);  // http:
  alert(location.host);      // localhost
  alert(location.origin);    // http://localhost
  alert(location.hash);      // #foobar
</script>
```

But none of them that I have been looking for because I wanna find the path for example "C:/xampp/htdocs/myCurrentDirectory". So How to do this...?

Thanks in advance... :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't.

Any connection between a URL and a file path is handled entirely internally by the HTTP server (and may not exist at all). Nothing about that relationship is exposed to the client, so client-side code can't know anything about it.