# How to get script url from file being imported in es6 modules javascript?

Tags: javascript, import, export, es6-modules

If some JS code has this

```
import("path/to/file.js")
```

and then file.js has this

```
export default async function() {
    // I want to get "path/to" here
    return {};
}
```

How can I get the directory of where `file.js` is?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13261970/how-to-get-the-absolute-path-of-the-current-javascript-file-name) do what you want?

Comment: dynamic imports are useless seeing as export does not wait for them.

Comment: did not help, but I figured it out. `import.meta.url`

Answer (score 1):

```
export default async function() {
    var current_file = import.meta.url;
    var dir_path = import.meta.url.substring(0, import.meta.url.lastIndexOf("/"));
    return {};
}
```

See compatibility here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import.meta