# How to detect if import.meta is supported by a browser?

Tags: javascript, es6-modules, browser-feature-detection

In JavaScript running in a browser, to get the current script URI, one can write like in https://stackoverflow.com/a/57364525/3102264:

```
let currentPath = import.meta.url.substring(
  0, import.meta.url.lastIndexOf("/"));
```

This works fine in a modern browser, however in an old browser it raises a `SyntaxError`.

I would like to detect if `import.meta` is supported in order to use `location.href` when it is not available.

I tried using try catch like

```
let currentPath;
try {
  currentPath  = import.meta.url.substring(
    0, import.meta.url.lastIndexOf("/"));
}
catch(e) {
  currentPath  = location.href.substring(
    0, location.href.lastIndexOf("/"));
}
```

But this is not working, it still throws

> Uncaught SyntaxError Unexpected token import

Is there a way to make conditional code depending on `import.meta` support?

Note: using location.href is an acceptable fallback when served from same based url (even it did not solve what allow import.meta)

Comment: `try { eval("import.meta"); } catch(e){ console.log( "Not supported" ); }`? Its pretty safe as long as you don't use eval for user input.

Comment: `import.meta` is always a syntax error in a direct `eval()`.

Comment: @somethinghere which is why I did not hammerclose. I would hazard a guess that most environments that supported the module supports the import and hence import.meta

Comment: @mplungjan unfortunately this is not the case, some browser support `<script type="module">` but not `import.meta`

Comment: @mplungjan `import` is not considered an object and `import.meta` is not considered a property access. They are special syntax.

Comment: Yeah, I just tried. `let bla = import.meta?.bla || null;` works, but `let bla = import?.bla || null;` give error on the optional chaining

Comment: @mplungjan this was my first try, before try/catch, this was working on browser supporting import.meta and raise syntaxerror on browser that did not.

Comment: The problem is that possible solutions will probably rely on other features that may also not be available in earlier implementations, for instance I was thinking `import("data:text/javascript,import.meta.url").then(() => console.log("supported")).catch(() => console.log("not supported"));` but that implies dynamic `import()` is itself supported, which, if we trust browser-compat-data would represent Chrome between v63 and v64 only...

Comment: Why not use `location.href` unconditionally?

Comment: @user3840170, because href doesnot give the correct path when script loaded from a webcomponent that import the script, it will give the href of the page.

Comment: @Kaiido `import("data:text/javascript,import.meta.url").then(() => console.log("supported")).catch(() => console.log("not supported"));` raise the same syntaxerror when not supported.

Comment: @mpromonet Then why bother with a fallback to `location.href` at all if it’s not going to give the right answer?

Comment: But it's caught in the `catch` callback, isn't it? You'd put your logic in either `.then()` for when it's supported or in `.catch()` for when it's not. Or are you trying in a browser that didn't support dynamic `import()`? In that case that's exactly the point of my comment, solutions would just make the range of unsupported browsers narrower, but it won't fill the whole gap.

Comment: By the way, it would be good if you could specify which browser and version you're using.

Comment: @Kaiido, no the catch is not called

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As noted in the comments, if you want a fallback for browsers not supporting `import.meta`, it’s not going to be as simple as replacing `import.meta.url` with `location.href`.  One will return the URI of the executing script, but the other will return the address of the page on which it runs, which may even be on a completely different domain.

That said, I managed to come up with a feature-detector that relies neither on user-agent sniffing, nor on dynamic `import()` expressions:

```js
const isImportMetaSupported = () => {
  const execModule = (src) => {
    const sc = document.createElement('script');
    sc.type = 'module';
    sc.textContent = src;
    document.body.appendChild(sc);
    sc.remove();      
  };

  const js = (pieces, ...values) =>
    String.raw({ raw: pieces }, ...values.map(x => JSON.stringify(x)));

  const gensym = () => {
    let ident;
    do {
      ident = `${2 * Math.random() / Number.EPSILON}$$`;
    } while (ident in window);
    return ident;
  };

  return new Promise((ok, ko) => {
    const $ok = gensym();
    window[$ok] = ok;
    execModule(js`
      window[${$ok}](true);
      import.meta;
    `);
    execModule(js`
      window[${$ok}](false);
      delete window[${$ok}];
    `);
    setTimeout(
      () => ko(new TypeError("modules unsupported?")), 1000);
  });
};

(async () => {
  const haveImportMeta = await isImportMetaSupported();
  console.log(
    `import.meta is ${haveImportMeta ? 'supported' : 'unsupported'}`);
  /*
    if (haveImportMeta)
      [load a script that uses import.meta]
    else
      [load a script that uses a fallback solution]
  */
})()
```

How it works: the detector attempts to execute two scripts.  If `import.meta` is supported, the first script executes and resolves the promise with a `true` value; if `import.meta` is not supported, the first script triggers a syntax error and does not execute.  The second script always executes and attempts to resolve the promise with a `false` value; if the first script had already executed, this has no effect.  I do use a few other advanced features, but those should be much easier to replace or polyfill than `import.meta` itself.

It’s a bit finicky: it relies on module scripts being executed in the order they are injected, which I am not sure is actually guaranteed.  If you worry about that, you can insert a couple of `setTimeout`s and let sleepsort deal with it.

Comment: Thanks your solution is complex but is working.

Answer (score 0):

> `import.meta` is always a syntax error in a direct `eval()`.

True: `import.meta` is restricted to module code, while `eval()` executes in a script context.

Conditional code depending on `import.meta` support is rather tricky to implement directly in the browser due to the parsing-time nature of syntax errors.

An alternative approach might involve using separate script files, but, as commented:

> The module and fallback scripts are still a reasonable idea, only they are available without reinventing the wheel by using `<script nomodule>` which only gets executed as a fallback when modules are not available.

That would mean:

- use `type="module"` for the script that utilizes `import.meta`. This script will only be executed in modern browsers that support ES6 modules and consequently `import.meta`.
- Use `nomodule` for the fallback script that employs `location.href`. This script will only be executed in browsers that do not support ES6 modules.

```html
<!-- For modern browsers that support ES6 modules and import.meta -->
<script type="module" src="module-script.js"></script>

<!-- Fallback for older browsers -->
<script nomodule src="fallback-script.js"></script>
```

In `module-script.js`:

```js
let currentPath = import.meta.url.substring(0, import.meta.url.lastIndexOf("/"));
// Rest of your code
```

In `fallback-script.js`:

```js
let currentPath = location.href.substring(0, location.href.lastIndexOf("/"));
// Rest of your code
```

---

> They are trying to specifically target the few browsers that did support type="module" but not import.meta, which was added a couple of browser shipments later.

If you are specifically targeting the rare set of browsers that support ES modules but not `import.meta`, I do not know of a browser-side solution. These browsers would execute the `type="module"` script and encounter a syntax error when they come across `import.meta`.

You might consider using a server-side user-agent string check to identify these specific browser versions and serve different scripts accordingly.

It would involve examining the `User-Agent` header sent by the browser in the HTTP request to identify the browser type and version, and, based on this information, serving different JavaScript files.

Something like (using Node.js and the Express framework for this example):

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.get('/your-script.js', (req, res) => {
  const userAgent = req.headers['user-agent'];

  // You would replace the following conditions with the specific user-agent strings 
  // or patterns that identify the browsers that support `type="module"` but not `import.meta`
  if (userAgent.includes('SomeOldBrowser')) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/fallback-script.js');
  } else {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/module-script.js');
  }
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('Server running on http://localhost:3000/');
});
```

In your HTML file, you would then simply link to this script:

```html
<script type="module" src="/your-script.js"></script>
```

The server will serve either `module-script.js` or `fallback-script.js` based on the user-agent string.

User-agent string checking is generally not recommended for feature detection due to various issues like browser spoofing, but it can serve as a workaround for this specific use-case.

---

> Interesting approach, but `import type="module"` is needed because there is a webcomponent in the code

If you are using web components, you likely have a build process where you are using tools like Webpack or Rollup. In that case, you might consider feature detection at build time, producing two different builds. You could then use server-side logic to serve the correct build based on the user agent.

Another idea is to isolate the specific logic that depends on `import.meta` into a separate JavaScript module file. You can then serve this isolated module conditionally based on server-side user-agent string checks. Once the appropriate module is loaded, you can import it dynamically into your main web component module script.

Create two separate JavaScript files:

- `importMetaLogic.js` for browsers that support `import.meta`

  ```js
  export const getCurrentPath = () => {
    return import.meta.url.substring(0, import.meta.url.lastIndexOf("/"));
  };
  ```
- `locationHrefLogic.js` for browsers that do not

  ```js
  export const getCurrentPath = () => {
    return location.href.substring(0, location.href.lastIndexOf("/"));
  };
  ```

On the server-side, conditionally serve one of these files based on the user-agent. Using Node.js and Express, the code might look like:

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.get('/logic.js', (req, res) => {
  const userAgent = req.headers['user-agent'];

  if (/* condition identifying browsers that support import.meta */) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/importMetaLogic.js');
  } else {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/locationHrefLogic.js');
  }
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('Server running on http://localhost:3000/');
});
```

In your main web component module script, dynamically import this logic:

```js
let getCurrentPath;

import('/logic.js')
  .then((module) => {
    getCurrentPath = module.getCurrentPath;
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error("An error occurred:", error);
  });

// Rest of your web component code
```

That uses the [dynamic `import()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/import) syntax, which returns a Promise. Unlike static `import`, dynamic `import()` can be used in any context and is not subject to the same restrictions as static `import`. That means you should be able to load modules conditionally at runtime.

`import('/logic.js')` returns a Promise that resolves into the imported module. Once the Promise is resolved, the `getCurrentPath` function from the dynamically loaded module is assigned to the local `getCurrentPath` variable. That makes the function available for use within the rest of your web component code.

That approach ensures that your main web component code remains largely unchanged. Only the logic that depends on `import.meta` or `location.href` is isolated into a separate module and conditionally loaded.

Comment: What's the point of `feature-detection.js` exactly? It's been a long day for me, but isn't just the same as `<script type="module" src="module-script.js"></script><script nomodule src="fallback-script.js"></script>`?

Comment: @VLAZ Good point. I have rewritten the answer using `<scipt nomodule>`

Comment: @Kaiido True. I have rewritten the answer without any `feature-detection.js`.

Comment: But this still doesn't quite match what OP is trying to get. They are trying to specifically target the few browsers that did support `type="module"` but not `import.meta`, which was added a couple of browser shipments later.

Comment: @Kaiido OK, I missed the nuance there. That looks like a server-side job. I have edited the answer.

Comment: @VonC Interesting approach, but `import type="module"` is needed because there is a webcomponent in the code.

Comment: @mpromonet OK. How about a dynamic import? I have edited the answer.

Comment: using server side logic is annoying, it create a coupling between js & http server.

Comment: @mpromonet I understand. I am glad you have gotten a better answer.