# $_GET inside javascript file?

Tags: javascript

For example, I have an script like this: `<script src="myjs.js?lol=asd"></script>`.

Is there anyway to get the `lol` inside the js file to alert it, for example, like we can do in PHP? Like:

```
var lol = $_GET['lol'];
alert(lol);
```

Comment: No. You can get the full URL of the page on which the script is executed easily, but a script does not know its own url (you only could search the DOM for matching `<script>` elements)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the code from [How may I reference the script tag that loaded the currently-executing script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/403967/how-may-i-reference-the-script-tag-that-loaded-the-currently-executing-script) to get a reference to the script tag:

```
var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
var thisScriptTag = scripts[scripts.length - 1];
```

Then you can use `thisScriptTag.src` to access its `src` attribute and parse it to get the variable you are looking for

Comment: +1, though this of course won't work for scripts not loaded through a `<script>` element (WebWorkers, ajax+eval etc.)

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this with javascript.