# JQuery selector of script tag calling from

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

i have the following html output of a tool thats i'm developing:

```
<button>a</button>
<script>$('what to wrtie here to select the previous button element?').click(function(){alert ('a clicked !');});</script>
<button>b</button>
<script>$('same here').click(function(){alert ('b clicked !');});</script>
```

i need the selector in each `script` tag to select the previous element.
using `id` selector cant be applied since the tool don't generate ids for elements.

thanks.

**ANSWER:**

```
$('script').last().prev().click(...
```

as Niklas said the current executed script is the last one in the list

Comment: please note that `alert ('x clicked !');` is just example, callback statements vary from button to another.

Comment: This seems like a really lousy way to do things, why do you need this?

Comment: Why not give the buttons IDs and use them in the selectors?

Comment: Check out this answer as it might help you on the way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/403967/how-may-i-reference-the-script-tag-that-loaded-the-currently-executing-script

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible without an id or some other kind of reference to either the button object or the script tag itself.

It's not possible to do because the script is not executed from where its element is located in the DOM. Instead it's executed with reference to the whole window.

Actually, there's a pretty good answer here: [How may I reference the script tag that loaded the currently-executing script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/403967/how-may-i-reference-the-script-tag-that-loaded-the-currently-executing-script)

In short, the currently running script is the last element in the list.

Comment: It is possible, but every time you use the approach an orphan dies of sadness.

Comment: thank you, that's right , i did it as you suggested
$('script').last().prev().click(

Answer (score 1):

There is no way of doing this (referring to the script tag that contains the script) that I know of. The best approach here would be to generate an ID for each element and aggregate your script into a single script tag.

---

That up there is the correct solution. The secret, naughty solution is this (spoiler):

> ```
> <button>a</button>
> <script>
>     //script#0001
>     $('script:contains("#0001")').prev().click(function(){
>         alert('foo');
>     });
> </script>
>
> <button>b</button>
> <script>
>     //script#0002
>     $('script:contains("#0002")').prev().click(function(){
>         alert('bar');
>     });
> </script>
> ```

**DON'T USE IT**

Comment: Why not just  $('script').prev().click(function(){...});​ on document ready function callback?

Comment: @roasted Because there are more than one scripts, and each is to have a different callback.

Answer (score 1):

well , i really don't recommend what you are doing first lets talk about your approach,
this kind of code should be wrapped in a `ready` event and when the `DOM` is ready all the registered code associated with that event will run , so no way to understand what script tag the code were in

---

what should happen is moving all the script tags to its own file and using selectors to select what elements you want or selecting them dynamicly using `prev`,`next`, `parents`, etc

**Edit**

i am wrong about not being able to get the script tag @Niklas answer is the right one, but i am still thinking very wrong to do so

Comment: you are right in general cases, but in my case, the code inside each `script` tag is accessing only the previous element, which of course has been loaded.