# Insert iframe at current script tag location?

Tags: javascript, dom

I've got what we'll just call a "widget"...and I want to insert that widget (ultimately just an `iframe`) at the current location of the script tag.

So you might have:

```
<p>Some example text</p>
<script src="http://example.com/widget.js" class="widget" async></script>
<p>More text</p>
```

In that `widget.js` file, there is this:

```
var createIframe = function() {
  var parent = document.getElementsByClassName('widget');
  var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');

  iframe.src = '//example.com'

  // Works, but just inserts it at the end
  document.body.appendChild(iframe);

  // Does not work...just doesn't seem to do anything
  document.createElement("div").appendChild(iframe);
}

window.onload = function() {
  createIframe();
}
```

And as noted in the code comment, doing `document.body.appendChild(iframe)` works fine, but just inserts the iframe at the very end of the document.

But what I really want to do is just insert the iframe right where the script tag is. That `document.body.appendChild(iframe)` is my attempt at it, but it literally just doesn't seem to do anything (no iframe and no errors).

So, how can I insert the iframe in the same spot as the script tag?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to [get the current `<script>` tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/403967/how-may-i-reference-the-script-tag-that-loaded-the-currently-executing-script), which in this case is the last one:

```
var thisScript = document.scripts[document.scripts.length - 1];
```

and [insert](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.insertBefore) the `<iframe>` after it:

```
var parent = thisScript.parentElement;
parent.insertBefore(iframe, thisScript.nextSibling);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/Tz75x/

Or simply [*replace*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.replaceChild) the current script with the `<iframe>`:

```
var parent = thisScript.parentElement;
parent.replaceChild(iframe, thisScript);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/a23XE/

---

Alternately – if you can believe it – **[`document.write()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.write) is actually a suitable solution here**, so long as you do it *while the document is loading* and not in a `window.onload` callback:

```
function createIframe() {
    document.write('<iframe src="//example.com"></iframe>');
}

createIframe();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/2YCcP

Comment: nextSibling is only supported since IE9 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TreeWalker.nextSibling

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up, but I'm entirely disinterested in supporting legacy IE in pretty much any of the code that I write. [jQuery 2 was released in April 2013](http://blog.jquery.com/2013/04/18/jquery-2-0-released/) and does not support IE <9. It's time to move on.

Comment: var thisScript = document.scripts[document.scripts.length - 1];
will only give you the current script if it is not embedded using async or defer attributes and not inserted by an async write.

Comment: Nowadays you can use `document.currentScript` to the exact script tag which loaded the script you're in. Supported on everything except IE -> https://caniuse.com/document-currentscript

Answer (score 1):

Add an ID to your `<script>` element and query this element from the DOM, e.g. `<script id="myscript" src="http://example.com/widget.js" class="widget" async></script>`.

In `widget.js`:

```
var scriptElement = document.getElementById("myscript");
var parentElement = scriptElement.parentElement;
parentElement.replaceChild(iframe, scriptElement);
```