# How to get id of javascript's container?

Tags: javascript

I would like to get `ID` of javascript's container, for ex:

```
<div id="d_17j_a">
   <script type="text/javascript">
      alert("<ID of javascript's container here>");
      // it will alert: d_17j_a
   </script>
</div>
```

(`ID` of div is dynamic)

Thank for any suggestion !

Comment: do you control the markup?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/q/403967/989121 for some suggestions

Comment: You should be able to start from here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/403967/218196.

Comment: @Kevin Bowersox: i am working with many dynamic html, so i would like to do that.

Comment: Are you going to have multiple scripts in a single div? or one div will contain 1 script at most?

Comment: @badZoke: i'm sure one div contain 1 script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<script id="FindMe" type="text/javasctipt">` should work just fine using `jQuery("#FindMe").parent().id`

In pure javascript

`document.getElementById("FindMe").parentNode.id`

Comment: Who said anything about jQuery?

Comment: Thank, it work for me with 'document.getElementById("FindMe").parentNode.id'

Answer (score 4):

So scripts are loaded sequentially, so you can get the parent node of a script element through:

```
var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
var me = scripts[scripts.length-1];
console.log('parent id', me.parentNode.id);
```

Comment: can use `document.scripts` ?

Comment: Just note that this approach works properly only if no scripts are deffered.

Comment: But, the SO has not mentioned anything w.r.t deferring scripts.

Answer (score 2):

If you can add an id to your script tag you can grab the parent with Javascript after retrieving the script element.

```
<div id="d_17j_a">
   <script id="myScript" type="text/javascript">
      var parentId = document.getElementById("myScript").parentNode.id;
      alert(parentId);
      // it will alert: d_17j_a
   </script>
</div>
```