# knowing the url of a script inside the script

Tags: javascript

So I have a script that is loaded dynamically into the page as so:

```
<div>
    <script>
        var url = 'http://example.com/scripts/myscript.js?foo=bar';
        document.write('<scr'+'ipt type=\"text/javascript\" src=\""+url+"\"></scri'+'pt>')
    </script>;
</div>
```

I need to know, if there is a way, inside the myscript.js i am loading, to access the url to get the query string.

Thanks

Comment: it'd be in the `url` var?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get query string values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1034621/get-current-url-with-javascript

Comment: Neither of those two "duplicates" answer this question, guys...

Comment: [I think this will help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/403967/how-may-i-reference-the-script-tag-that-loaded-the-currently-executing-script)

Comment: If the script is executed immediately (no async/defer), you can use the same method as described here to get access to the script element: http://ejohn.org/blog/degrading-script-tags/

Answer (score 3):

When a script is running (unless you add `defer` or `async` attributes), it will always be the last element on the page so far. You can therefore take advantage of this fact:

```
var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script'),
    currentScript = scripts[scripts.length-1],
    myScriptURL = currentScript.getAttribute("src");
```

You can then process that `myScriptURL` variable to extract query string paramters, as demonstrated in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values).

Comment: even if the script is injected at a later time, and has some script tags below?

Comment: That would count as deferring the script, which causes this method to fail.