# jQuery Select current script tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

Does somebody know if its possible to select the current script-tag with jQuery without any other selectordefinitions?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready( function(){
    // Here i need to select the current tag "<script ..."
})
</script>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How may I reference the script tag that loaded the currently-executing script?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/403967/how-may-i-reference-the-script-tag-that-loaded-the-currently-executing-script)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Outside the document ready method, just do `$('script').last();`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var currentScript = $('script').last();
$(document).ready( function(){
    //Use the variable currentScript here
})
</script>
```

Or simply give an id to your script.

Comment: I presume this won't work if the original script tag had the `defer` or `async` attributes set.

Comment: This doesn't make sense at all. It makes a huge assumption that your script tag is the last one in the page.

Comment: ↑ It is last one at the moment of its execution, that's why the code must be outside the `ready` event callback.

Comment: Is this true when there are other tags with `async` on them?

Comment: @cjm2671The ID part works no matter what, as long as the ID is unique. The snippet works as long as the tag containing the specified code is not `async`

Answer (score 7):

The most robust way to achieve this is:

```
<script>
 (function(script){
    //do whatever you want with script here...
 })(document.currentScript);
</script>
```

It is more robust than other solutions because you may also use it after the document has loaded. Also it does not require the definition of a variable (if you have several script tags this might be an issue since you cannot reuse the same variable name). With JQuery:

```
<script>
     (function(script){
        $(document).ready(function(){
            // do whatever you want after the DOM as loaded here...
        });
     })(document.currentScript);
</script>
```

Answer (score 5):

I think this is fastest way

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName("script");
    var thisScript = scripts[scripts.length - 1];
</script>
```

Comment: I like the non-jQuery approach

Comment: I presume this won't work if the original script tag had the `defer` or `async` attributes set.

Comment: What if there are multiple script tags on the page? This doesn't select the script tag that surrounds the current javascript. It just selects the last one on the page.

Comment: @JakeWilson As commented on Karl-André Gagnon's similar answer, when the browser encounters this script tag, it is the last one on the page (as long as `defer` or `async` aren't set).

Answer (score 2):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var currentScript = document.currentScript || (function() {
     var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
     return scripts[scripts.length - 1];
  })();
<script/>
```

`document.currentScript` works on most browsers and `scripts[scripts.length - 1]` is the fallback for the other ones (wich may impose some restrictions to `<script async>`).

[Further discussion](http://2ality.com/2014/05/current-script.html)

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName("script");
var thisScript = scripts[scripts.length - 1];
```

Comment: This returns the `type` attribute of *all* script tags.

Comment: The previous comment refers to a prior version of this answer.  The current answer is now similar to several other answers on this page.