# Get DOM element containing a Javascript snippet

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to get a reference to the container of a Javascript function?

To give an example:

```
<div>
  <script>
   var thisDiv = ???
   doSomething(thisDiv);
  </script>
</div>
```

It seems that the `this` keyword only refers to the containing element when it is triggered by direct event such as `onClick()`. Otherwise `this` refers to the containing `window` element. Is there any equivalent way to get the parent or containing element of a `<script>` snippet ?

Comment: Related: [How may I reference the script tag that loaded the currently-executing script?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/403967/218196). FYI, elements don't create *scope*. There is only global scope and function scope. A script element doesn't create scope.

Comment: @FelixKling: Thanks. I just used 'scope' for the lack of a better word. I will change the title to clear any ambiguity.

Answer (score 1):

There is no *completely* reliably approach. The closest you can come is to find the last script element in the DOM (with `document.getElementsByTagName`) and then navigate from there (`parentNode` et al).

That can break if the script element was inserted dynamically or used `defer` or `async`.

Comment: If possible you're better off `id`ing the divs that contain the scripts

Comment: What if I combine the `parentNode` of your solution, with a solution in the link @FelixKling suggested, something like: `var thisDiv =  document.currentScript.parentNode;`. Would that work?