# How to append text to current position?

Tags: javascript

```
<div>
HI!
<script>
var spanNode = document.createElement('span');
var textNode = document.createTextNode('there.');
//how to append here spanNode?
</script>
How are you?
</div>
```

I don't want to use document.write() method. So, what should I use here so the result would be like this:

```
<div>HI!<span>there.</span>How are you?</div>
```

Comment: Do you want a way to append the span according to the position of the script tag?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A `<script>` element by default is executed immediately, so at the moment of execution there's just `<div>HI! <script />` in the document, the "How are you" part hasn't been processed yet. At this moement the currently processed `<script>` element will be the last of script elements in your document so you can reference it using `document.scripts[ document.scripts.length - 1 ]`, then find its parent node and append the elements.

```
<div>
HI!
<script>
var spanNode = document.createElement('span');
var textNode = document.createTextNode('there.');
    spanNode.appendChild( textNode );
/* this is the currently interpreted <script> element
   so you can append a child to its parent.
*/
document.scripts[ document.scripts.length - 1 ].parentNode.appendChild( spanNode );
</script>
How are you?
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/0LsLq9x7/

Edit: to keep the global namespace clean you could wrap the code in an anonymous function which executes immediately: http://jsfiddle.net/0LsLq9x7/1/

```
<div>
HI!
<script>
(function( scriptElement ){
    // these variables will be local to this closure
    var spanNode = document.createElement('span');
    var textNode = document.createTextNode('there.');
    spanNode.appendChild( textNode );
    scriptElement.parentNode.appendChild( spanNode );
// pass a reference to the script element as an argument to the function
}(document.scripts[ document.scripts.length - 1 ]));
</script>
How are you?
</div>
```

Comment: That's correct way to do it. @NavinRauniyar Since browser renders one element at a time (and since script is not `deferred/async`) by the time `scipt` tag is visited it is guarantied that this is the **last** script tag. So `document.scripts[ document.scripts.length - 1 ]` selects current script.

Comment: @NavinRauniyar added an explanation in the answer, but the currently processed script is the last script in the document, because the rest hasn't been loaded yet :) (doesn't apply to deferred / async scripts).

Comment: I used this code and no matters where the script tag in document but works great. Thank you.

Comment: @dfsq what if used defer="defer" ?

Comment: @pawel I'm still unclear with the code. How is it appending right after the script tag?

Comment: @NavinRauniyar Then proper result is not guarantied.

Comment: For this problem this is a good solution. But there are problems with this approach if the script contains asynchronous functions (like Ajax). Aslo this doesn't work if the script is added dynamically.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/403967/how-may-i-reference-the-script-tag-that-loaded-the-currently-executing-script

Comment: @plbsam the second solution will work with AJAX with a minor tweak, using `insertBefore` instead of `appendChild`: http://jsfiddle.net/0LsLq9x7/3/  (using `setTimeout` for async execution, but the same applies to ajax callback).

Comment: @pawel  Ah. Good to know that. I just referenced something I found. I think what it meant was, document.scripts couldn't be used inside callbacks... Btw why did you use a temporary scoop? Is it necessary? http://jsfiddle.net/0LsLq9x7/4/

Comment: @plbsam like I said - to keep the variables from polluting the global scope.

Answer (score 0):

You can first get the current script. Then add the element before (or after) the script..

```html
<div>
HI!
<script id="myscript">
var spanNode = document.createElement('span');
var textNode = document.createTextNode('there.');
    spanNode.appendChild( textNode );
  
    //appending the span node
    var ele = document.currentScript;   //get current script element
    ele.parentNode.insertBefore(spanNode,ele);  //append the span before the script
</script>
How are you?
</div>
```

Comment: Oh wow this would be great if browser support wasn't lacking.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/currentScript