# Add div between element

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have 2 paragraph and in between, I'll call a function. This function is to create a new div between the paragraph.

```
<div id="container">
    <p>lorem ipsum</p>
    <script>createDiv()</script>
    <p>lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>lorem ipsum</p>
</div>
```

I've seen `append()`, but it need a target to append. I want to add the div automatically every time I call the function.

Also, `document.write()` but this will clear the paragraph.

There's multiple paragraph on the same page, and I can't add id or class to these paragraph. I don't have control over them.

Comment: Do you mean something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27481198/how-to-append-text-to-current-position

Comment: Why can't you edit the HTML? Are these paragraphs in a container div? There is no way to determine which p tags are which without an id or class unless they are within a div with an id or class.

Comment: @MrBearAndBeer your answer adds the div inside the targeted p tag. OP wants it right after. Also he has mentioned that he can't edit the HTML so you won't be able to add an ID to the p tag.

Comment: @JoeMoe1984 update the markup. Thats all I have control over.

Comment: @baker my answer assumes you have jQuery loaded on that page. Is that correct? Or do you have to use javascript without any libraries loaded?

Comment: I have jQuery loaded on the same page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll start off by saying, what you're trying to do is extremely ugly. Given your constraints, it's very likely there is something else fundamentally wrong with your app's structure. I even feel a bit dirty giving you this solution.

Regardless, to answer your question literally with the code examples and requirements you specified, you would likely need to keep a global counter of your script injection tags so you could append to its previous sibling. Here's an example that should do what you want w/ a fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/h5qttvx5/3/).

**Given HTML**

```
<div id="container">
<p>lorem ipsum</p>
<script>createDiv()</script>
<p>lorem ipsum</p>
<p>lorem ipsum</p>
<script>createDiv()</script>
</div>
```

And JS (in head)

```
var scripts = 0;
function createDiv() {
    $("#container > script").eq(scripts).prev().after("<div>HI</div>");
    scripts++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this : remove script call and assign id to first paragraph, then use `.after()` to append div

```
<p id="firstP">lorem ipsum</p>
<p>lorem ipsum</p>
```

Note : -  You can use `class` attribute for first `p` element instead of `id` and modify your jQuery selector as per like `$('.className')`

Use `.after()`

```
$(function(){
  $('#firstP').after('<div>Your div </div>');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First create a function and give it a name createDiv:

```
<script>
    function createDiv(div) {
       document.write('<div>Testing</div>');
    }
</script>
```

Them call the function where you want put the new div:

```
<p>lorem ipsum</p>
<script>createDiv()</script>
<p>lorem ipsum</p>
```

**OBS: The script must be in the HEAD.**

Comment: This will add div inside `p` tag but OP want it in between two `p` tags

Comment: This doesn't work!! Copy-pasting your solution in jsfiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/L6c6roc8/ . No div is added between the two paragraph tags, or for that matter, within the paragraph tag. ***This answer does not even remotely answer the OP's question.***

Answer (score 0):

If you append inside the p tag:

```
 $('p').append('<div>xyz</div>');
```

If you append in between to p tag as sibling:

```
 $('<div>xyz</div>').insertAfter('p:first');
```

Comment: there's multiple <p> on the same page. doing this will create div on other <p> as well.

Comment: Wouldn't this add a div inside the p tag? I believe the OP wanted it in between the p tags not inside

Answer (score 0):

change your markup to

```
<p id="lorem">lorem ipsum</p>
 <div id="thediv">
 </div>
<p>lorem ipsum</p>
```

and call `$("#thediv").append("<div>append div</div>");`

[**DEMO FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/xbzx2p6r/)

**OR**

```
  $('#lorem').after('<div>append div </div>');
```

[**DEMO FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/tyuyvak6/)

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("p:first").after("<div>Hello World</div>");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>lorem ipsum</p>

<p>lorem ipsum</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

This code should work fine, if I understand your problem well enough.

```
<p>lorem ipsum</p>
<script>document.write('<div>Testing</div>')</script>
<p>lorem ipsum</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

since you have the div container with an id you can target that and work your way down. Try the following:

```
$('#container > p:first').after('<div>hello</div>');
```

This will target the first p tag in the container div and add a div right after it.

Performance wise you may want to use the first() method instead of the pseudo class :first.

```
$('#container > p').first().after('<div>hello</div>');
```

This Stackoverflow question has answers that show tests for both cases:
[jQuery :first vs. .first()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2312761/jquery-first-vs-first)