# jQuery replaceWith to remove <script> tag content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this:

```
<div class="myclass">
<script type="text/javascript">
functions inside;
</script>
</div>
```

and I need to have this:

```
<div class="myclass">
</div>
```

I tried with:

```
jQuery("div.myclass").replaceWith("");
```

but it doesn't work. **The code delete only div, not script tag.**

Any idea? 
thanks

Comment: Did you try `jQuery("div.myclass").html("")` ?

Comment: What does _does not work_ mean? `div` not became empty? or the funtions that existed before you ran your script still work?

Comment: Did you forget to save the file and/or refresh the browser?

Answer (score 2):

Try [empty()](https://api.jquery.com/empty/)

```
jQuery("div.myclass").empty();
```

Comment: @Laboo, can you put it up in a fiddle?

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing the HTML of the div instead of the div itself:

```
jQuery("div.myclass").html("");
```

Or, target the script tag:

```
jQuery("div.myclass script").replaceWith("");
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/wn2c5kgb/
If you inspect the source of the frame, you'll see that the script tag is removed.  Comment out the Javascript on the left, re run the fiddle, inspect the source, and you'll notice it is back.  Are you receiving any console errors when you attempt these solutions?

Comment: the script I want to remove countains a "src" to another js. That js starts before div is removed

Comment: If you want to target a script tag by a particular src, without any other defining attributes you can use:  jQuery('script[src="mysrc.js"]').replaceWith("");

Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/403967/how-may-i-reference-the-script-tag-that-loaded-the-currently-executing-script

Comment: .html("") doas work, unlike .empty() which leaves the script code.