# Javascript current script tag

Tags: javascript

*Self Answering this question:*

Using *document.currentScript* is not supported by IE.

Using

```
var scripts document.getElementsByTagName('scripts');
var script=scripts[scripts-1]
```

does not work asynchronously.

I ran into a very rare circumstance where using DOM selectors was not an option either.

```
ie document.getElementById('myScript');
```

Is there a way to execute the script where "this" refers to the script tag?

Answer (score 0):

for previous discussion on this see

[How may I reference the script tag that loaded the currently-executing script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/403967/how-may-i-reference-the-script-tag-that-loaded-the-currently-executing-script)

My solution was to do this...

```
<h1> 
     <script onload='new Function(this.innerHTML).call(this)' src=' '>
                if(this!=window){
                    this.parentNode.innerHTML='HELLO THERE!';
                }
     </script>
</h1>
```

IE requires the SRC attribute to have at least one blank space. src='' will not work in IE.

Comment: Afaik setting `src` will block the inline script within a script tag.

Comment: @Teemu Yeah. The if(this!=window) condition was not necessary in modern FF and IE for the reason you mention, but I left it there since I didn't test every browser version.