# Javascript : Get the last executed script

Tags: javascript, element

This is with reference to the question :
[How may I reference the script tag that loaded the currently-executing script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/403967/how-may-i-reference-the-script-tag-that-loaded-the-currently-executing-script)

And the most upvoted answer.
It mentions in option 6 :
"6. Get the last executed script"

Problems

```
Does not work with asynchronous scripts (defer & async)
Does not work with scripts inserted dynamically
```

My script is not async, but the page might have other scripts that are async or defer. Would this option work in that case as well? I have not been able to find an answer to this anywhere.

Comment: Not necessarily, no.  If you don't need IE support, check out: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/currentScript

Comment: @Scott'scm6079' : document.currentScript is definitely the cleanest solution and I would've gone for it, but unfortunately, I do need IE support.

Comment: @humble.rumble : For some reason, I don't want to assign an id to the script tag. So that is not an option.

Comment: Note that *currentScript* only tells you the script that is executing if it's called while the script is loading. Once the load event has occurred, there is no *currentScript*. Why do you need to know? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Not sure the details of your needs - but since you are putting a script on a remote site, you could have the script you distribute do nothing but dynamically create a new script node, which you can have a handle to.  Depending on why you need to know the script tag, that can help... I've got lots of tricks, but need to know a little more about what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: @humble.rumble : I might have to include the script at multiple places in the target webpage. It is somewhat like an ad tag. I want to insert the ad at the node where my script resides. I don't want to create a new id for each place since I am not putting the script tag in the page (the page owner would be supposed to do that and I don't want to rely on him to generate a new id, etc).

Comment: @humble.rumble : Thanks. The only doubt I had was in the case when the page might have other script tags which could be asynchronous. Would the solution work in that case as well?

Answer (score -1):

If I understand you problem, I think closures would help solve this.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures

You may also want to organize your JS files so that your async files are included in an async.js file and non-acyned files in non_async.js and so on.

I hope this is clear.

Cheers,

Tim

Comment: Tim: The problem is that I don't own the website. I am just giving out a small script to the site owner to be included in his/her page. So I have no control over everything else that the site owner has.

Comment: I see.  Then the closure like is for you.

Comment: Closures are an artefact of javascript's lexical scoping, they have nothing to do with linking a particular execution context to the script element that created it.