# Get variable in JavaScript without clicking

Tags: javascript

I am trying to display some banner from a remote location using `hrefs` and `img` in JavaScript.

On client side:

```
<script src="data/JScript.js?id=123" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I want some solution so that I can make 123 dynamic in below JS file. As of now it is hard coded.

I just want that i will give client the above JS link and it will generate
a dynamic link to a website with a querystring paramenter like (www.abc.com/123)

JS file (JScript.js):

```
document.write('<div style="text-align:center" class="img-responsive" ><a href="www.test.com/123" > <img style="width:200px;height:200px;" src="http://pixel.nymag.com/imgs/daily/intelligencer/2015/07/18/20-donald-trump.w529.h352.2x.jpg" alt="" > </img> </a> </div>');
```

Comment: looks like you need this http://feather.elektrum.org/book/src.html

Comment: The link provided by @atinder is no longer necessary.  See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/403967/how-may-i-reference-the-script-tag-that-loaded-the-currently-executing-script) answer for several better options

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your script runs you can search for your script tag on the page then parse the query string

```
var el = document.querySelector('script[src^="http://example.com/path/to/script.js"]');
var num = /\?id=(\d+)/.exec(el.src)[1];
document.write('<div style="text-align:center" class="img-responsive" ><a href="www.test.com/'+num+'" > <img style="width:200px;height:200px;" src="http://pixel.nymag.com/imgs/daily/intelligencer/2015/07/18/20-donald-trump.w529.h352.2x.jpg" alt="" > </img> </a> </div>');
```

Comment: You can also use ```document.currentScript``` to get the script element that the code is running from.

Comment: Thanks Nik, didn't know about that!