# Accessing currently executing JavaScript path when jQuery's getScript() Method is used

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a JavaScript file, which needs to know from which location it is loaded. My requirement is similar to [How may I reference the script tag that loaded the currently-executing script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/403967/how-may-i-reference-the-script-tag-that-loaded-the-currently-executing-script)

I am using

```
document.currentScript;
```

to get the script path. But this implementation is breaking if my JavaScript file is loaded using jQuery's getScript() Method:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $.getScript("my_script.js");
   });
});
```

When I do this, document.currentScript always returns null. Is there a work around to fix this issue?

Comment: `$.getScript` doesn't use a script tag, it uses ajax with the `script` dataType to get and load the script, which is why `currentScript` probably is null. Why do you need to know which location the script was loaded from, it seems like a X/Y problem, and the really simple solution is to just check for a certain element in the current DOM to see what page you're on.

Comment: My script file could change regularly and I have no control over who uses it. So if my script is not loaded from my domain, I simply log a message indicating to developers that they should check if script has been updated. Can you please share more information on "check for a certain element in the current DOM to see what page you're on."

Comment: Did you try using `document.domain` to get the current domain in your script file

Comment: Hey Thanks. This gives me the domain name. document.documentURI gives the complete URL. Can you please post this as the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `$.ajaxSetup()` , `beforeSend`

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  beforeSend:function(jqxhr, settings) {
    // do stuff with path to current `url`
    console.log(settings.url)
  }
})
```

Comment: I added this before making call to "getScript("my_script.js");". The log in this method gives a url, but how do I access the information in my script file. Since my script is not added to script dataType.

Comment: Is requirement to return text of `"my_script.js"` ?

Comment: yes. document.documentURI seems to be working. But I need to test it.