# How to get the surrounding DOM element from Javascript located inside

Tags: javascript

Is it possible with Javascript to get the DOM element surrounding my script tag?

Example:

```
<div>
    <script>
        // get the DOM element of the surrounding <div> tag here
    </script>
</div>
```

I won't/can't use id's or something similar on the div, because they would have to be randomly generated to be unique. I'm looking for a clean approach. There could be any number of these DIV's with Javascript inside.

Comment: Have you tried any code?

Comment: So you ***can't*** use IDs because of the unknown nature of them. That's fine. If you **could** but ***won't*** then that's all on you.

Comment: I agree with @JamesThorpe. Read that and then select the parent of the script element. Edit: Here is the link he referenced - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/403967/how-may-i-reference-the-script-tag-that-loaded-the-currently-executing-script

Comment: @Toiletduck Just FYI - when questions are closed as dupes, the links that were in the original comment end up in the yellow box at the top of the question - it didn't get lost during the process :)

Comment: I see. The questioned hadn't been closed off on my screen yet, your comment was just gone so I figured I would post the link. But thanks for the info bud.