# Get script-tag that called certain function

Tags: javascript, resources, load

Let's say I have **first** script, that contains function export

```
function export(*params*){
  let callerScriptReference = ....;
  .....
}
```

then I have a **second** script, where I call this function

```
export(*params*);
```

Is it possible to get reference to that second script from within export function body? I'd like to get some "data-*" attribute from that script tag.

Scripts are added to the page in random order.

Hopefully you understand what I'm trying to accomplish :D

Thanks for any suggestions or help.

Comment: just find the script tag, you don't need the script contents.

Comment: Can you put it in an argument to the `export()` function? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/403967/how-may-i-reference-the-script-tag-that-loaded-the-currently-executing-script for how the caller can get a reference to their own script tag.

Comment: Yes, I can pass it as a parameter. But I'm creating a little framework that loads resources dynamically in the browser. No bundling, no concatenation. (optimized for http/2). And everything that shortens the syntax is much appretiated. In fact, I want to specify module-name in "data-module" attribute. This attribute then tells me, from within which module the export function was called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, there's no built-in way to get information about the `<script>` tag that contains the calling code, so you'll need to pass it explicitly.

```
function export(callerscript, otherparams...) {
    ...
}
```

The caller would do:

```
export(document.currentScript, otherargs...);
```

If you're doing it in a function, you can capture the value in a closure variable using an IIFE.

```
var someFun = (function(curScript) {
                return function(stuff) {
                    export(curScript, stuff);
                }; })(document.currentScript);
someFun(stuffArgs);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are in the browser you can just add another script tag in the html body.  This will allow the function to share the same scope.

If you are in nodejs, if you are using ES5 (most supported currently):

- script1.js has at the end:

module.exports = function funName() { }

- script2.js has at the beginning:

var funName = require('script1');

Comment: How would you get an attribute of the `<script>` tag with that code?

Comment: I don't think you understand the question.

Comment: Check out this jQuery method for loading scripts: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/

Comment: I'm sorry but you have no idea what I'm trying to do.

Comment: What does the method of loading scripts have to do with this question? He wants to get an HTML attribute of the `<script>` tag that contains the caller's script.