# Is it possible to reference to an element in the document via context?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The classic way to access an element would be:

```
<div id="myId"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#myId').something();
    });
</script>
```

Let alone the many times when there is no clear id to use to access an element, where we end up using the class attribute's value(s), but we can never be sure if there is more than just one such element in the page.

After writing this or similar code thousands of times, i got to wonder:

**Is there a way to use context to directly reference a HTML element?**

I'm thinking of something like this:

```
<div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $.getContext().something(); // accessing the encapsulating div
        });
    </script>
</div>
```

Or anything similar?

Comment: By context you mean text ?

Comment: By context i mean context.

Comment: See [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/403967/how-may-i-reference-the-script-tag-that-loaded-the-currently-executing-script) then just get its parent BUT you cannot use it from document ready handler, just at time it is processed

Comment: I'm not sure what the advantage would be, you're still searching for something using the DOM.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you mean by 'context'

Comment: You could achieve this behaviour if you really want, but this is not worth it. Organize your code properly, write selectors wisely and you will not have any problems with contexts. In addition with good frameworks and methodologies (react, angular, vue, etc.) you get rid of the problem entirely since DOM jQuery-style manupulations just are not in play anymore.

Comment: How would it be achieved? Looking for answers. I'm not really having any particular problems with the classic approach, and it's not like using another approach would set a milestone in better coding. Nevertheless i look for a solution, be it only to understand how it would be done.

Comment: So what you want is something like that?! (but doesn't work on older browsers and all IEs): https://jsfiddle.net/0yft8xzc/

Comment: @A.Wolff – this looks promising! Perhaps you want to post this as an answer?

Comment: @SquareCat This looks like a dupe of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/403967/how-may-i-reference-the-script-tag-that-loaded-the-currently-executing-script) to me

Comment: Not sure about that. I am not looking to reference the script tag. I want to reference any element in the page i embed the script tag in.

Comment: Your question could be legit but i guess this is more a XY problem. How do you embed the script tag? Is that following any user interaction like for a WYSIWYG editor? Couldn't you just give ID to this specific script tag?

Comment: Perhaps it's a bit more of a meta-question, as this is not so much about practicability as it is about curiosity and better understanding. I am looking for a way to get around using selectors to access elements when the context is clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass an optional second context parameter to your [`jQuery(selector, context)`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/) where `context` is:

> A DOM Element, Document, or jQuery to use as context

For instance, in your example you could pass `this` to your selector to reference the `document` context:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myId', this).something();
});
```

The example is contrived because of the ID selector though, and since document is the default context. A better example would be something like:

```
$('div.foo').click(function() {
    $('span', this).addClass('bar');
});
```

Comment: I was unaware that `.context` actually existed. Funny. Anyway, while i am grateful for the contribution, this is not what i was looking for. Here i still require the element's id (or class or whatever) to reference it.

Comment: Question is maybe unclear but this has nothing to do with jQuery context option

Comment: I see. The original edit had `.context()` function which led me to the deprecated jQuery function.

Comment: Sorry about that – i chose `.context` just as an example, so i edited the question to make things more clear.