# How to get URL of loaded script in javascript

Tags: javascript

On my site `mysite.com` I load scripts from `anothersite.com`. Is there a way for a script running on `mysite.com` to know that it was downloaded from `anothersite.com`?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you need this?

Comment: You can write an interceptor and tag the request going for script loading to other domains ?

Comment: If the `script` knows the name of itself. And checks the `<script>` `src` attribute like `getAttribute('src')`. And then `window.location.origin`. It can do.

Comment: how do you load them?

Comment: The script is loaded on unknown site and the script needs to write script etc. Needs the unknown starting point

Answer (score 1):

I found this to the the solution:

```
    function serverName() {

    var server = "";

    //IE and EDGE can't use the case-insensitive 'i' in this selector
    var path = $('script[src*="loader.js"]').attr('src'); //Look for the script tag of this script and get the URL

    var regex = RegExp('.*\/\/.*?\/'); // gets this: http://mysite/
    var m = regex.exec(path);
    if (m && m.length) {
        server = m[0].replace(/\/$/, "");//trim trailing slash
    }

    return server;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
const domain = location.hostname;
```

See more about [`location.hostname`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_hostname.asp)

> The `hostname` property sets or returns the hostname of a URL.

Comment: Doesn't though tell me where the external script was loaded from, just eh consuming server.

Comment: You may be looking for [`document.currentScript`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/403967) which you can then do `document.currentScript.getAttribute('src')`

Comment: document.currentScript is great, but we have to support older browsers and IE still. Ugh

Answer (score -2):

```html
<!doctype HTML>
    <html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.6.1/react.min.js" id="know"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        Hello
        <script>
         const gebi=id=>document.getElementById(id)
         console.log(gebi('know').src)
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

This would work