# Getting the parent element from the location of the called function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, parent

Is possible to getting parent element from the location of the called function?

my case:

```
<div class="alphabet">
    <div class="lorem">
      <script type="text/javascript">
        getParent();
      </script>
    </div>

    <div class="ipsum">
      <script type="text/javascript">
        getParent();
      </script>
    </div>

    <div class="dolor">
      <div class="amet">
        <script type="text/javascript">
          getParent();
        </script>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
<script>
function getParent(){

  //......????????.......//

}
</script>
```

Expected Result (Console Log):

1. getParent() > the parent is **lorem**
2. getParent() > the parent is **ipsum**
3. getParent() > the parent is **amet**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How may I reference the script tag that loaded the currently-executing script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/403967/how-may-i-reference-the-script-tag-that-loaded-the-currently-executing-script)

Comment: no... its different question

Comment: @AbuAyyub actually if it really is a different question, then my answer below is wrong o.O But then can you explain?

Comment: ok, i get that point, the main solution is "document.currentScript"... sorry for my mistake, still newbie :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work, although my intuition tells me you're doing something wrong.

```
<script>
    function getParent(){
        var me = document.currentScript;
        var parent = me.parentElement;
        console.log(parent.className);
        return parent;
    }
</script>
<div class="lorem">
  <script type="text/javascript">
    getParent();
  </script>
</div>

<div class="ipsum">
  <script type="text/javascript">
    getParent();
  </script>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8tjsa8fw/

Comment: Sure:) But again - you're doing something wrong. Why not make a script below your html and then reference the divs with e.g.document.querySelectorAll('.someClass').forEach(element){...}; i.e. like this is normally done? :) BBL

Comment: because i need the current parent of the function called when i load some page from ajax.

Comment: and i put the script before </body> not in <head>, so that it is ran after all the elements have been rendered.