# How to find out where current script-tag is located?

Tags: javascript

I have an HTML like this

```
<div id="content">
    <h1>Shop Sample</h1>
    <h2>View HTML-Source to see the embedded js</h2>

    <script src="js/faq_embd.js"></script>
    <div id="response-area">

    </div>
</div>
```

Now the `faq_embd.js` is supposed to render html right under its own `<script>` Tag.

In js, how do I find out where the  Tag is and how do I append under it?

Comment: Take a look at this answer, it describes how to work with script tag references very well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22745553/6524598

Comment: I don't think such kind of built-in function available which can let you know about location of element

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How may I reference the script tag that loaded the currently-executing script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/403967/how-may-i-reference-the-script-tag-that-loaded-the-currently-executing-script)

Comment: This really sounds like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Please explain whole issue in more detail

Comment: I would suggest to not pick the place to render based around where the script tag appears, but target the div instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following. This will set a paragraph right below the script.
You can verify by checking the DOM

```js
document.getElementsByTagName("script")[1].insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', '<p id="idChild"> content html </p>');
```

```html
<div id="content">
    <h1>Shop Sample</h1>
    <h2>View HTML-Source to see the embedded js</h2>

    <script src="js/faq_embd.js"></script>
    <div id="response-area">

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can locate the current script element using `document.currentScript`. Note that Internet Expolorer does not support it at all (view compatibility table at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/currentScript), so a simple way to get the current script element in a corss-browser way is to give your tag a fixed id, then locate it with `document.getElementById()`.

For performace reasons, before using the DOM, try to retrive the current script tag with `document.currentScript`.

As an example, having an html like this

```
<div id="content">
  <h1>Shop Sample</h1>
  <h2>View HTML-Source to see the embedded js</h2>
  <script id="script-id" src="js/faq_embd.js"></script>
  <div id="response-area"></div>
</div>
```

You could use this code to create a new paragraph just under the current script tag:

```
var yourScript = document.currentScript || document.getElementById("script-id");
var yourParagraph = document.createElement("p");
if (yourScript.nextSibling){
  yourScript.parentNode.insertBefore(yourParagraph, parentGuest.nextSibling);
} else {
  yourScript.parentNode.appendChild(yourParagraph);
}
```