# Get the file name of the current ES module

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

Is it possible to get the file name of the current JavaScript [module](https://v8.dev/features/modules)?

```js
// item.mjs
function printName() {
  console.log(...);  // >> item or item.mjs
};
```

If not, why not? Sandboxing, etc.

Comment: In Node.js it's just `__filename__`. If you're looking for a client-side solution, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22745553/1541563).

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Thanks but I'm not talking about Node.js files.

Comment: Are you talking about files loaded with script tags or you are using some js framework, where you need file name?

Comment: @MahendraPratap I'm talking about JavaScript modules imported with a script tag (i.e. `<script src="item.mjs" type="module"></script>`).

Comment: You can get scripts by document.getElementsByTagName('script') and then check there src for getting name, but getting current module name would not be possible i think.

Comment: Do you have the ability to modify the modules or are they out of your control?

Comment: @daddygames I can modify the modules.

Comment: @isar Clientside ES6 modules with no transpilation step? Then surely you're also brave enough to use [this experimental feature](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-import-meta) :-)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You are looking for the ([proposed](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-import-meta)) [`import.meta`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import.meta) meta property. What exactly this object holds depends on the environment, but in a browser you can use

```
// item.mjs
function printName() {
  console.log(import.meta.url);  // https://domain.example/js/item.mjs
}
```

You can extract the file name by parsing that with the [`URL` interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL), e.g.

```
console.log(new URL(import.meta.url).pathname.split("/").pop())
```

Answer (score 4):

```js
import { basename, dirname } from "node:path";
import { fileURLToPath } from "node:url";

const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
const __dirname = dirname(__filename);

const filename = basename(__filename);
```

... another example:

```
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from "node:url";

const rootDir = fileURLToPath(new URL("..", import.meta.url));
```

Alternatively, use [`zx`](https://github.com/google/zx#readme) script runner that sets `__filename`, `__dirname`.

Answer (score -1):

One potential solution: Each method in the mjs file may set a global variable that will be the name of the module. The `printName()` method would then print the current value of that global variable. That way, while processing, you can inspect the current state of that global variable for the name of the file currently executing.

global js

```
var global_mjs_name = 'none';

function printName() {
   console.log('processed in ' + global_mjs_name);
}

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(event){
    printName(); // output -> 'none'
    doWork({}); 
    printName(); // output -> 'item.mjs'
    doFunStuff();
    printName(); // output -> 'FunStuff.mjs'
});
```

inside item.mjs:

```
const item_js_name = 'item.mjs';

function doWork(data) {
   global_mjs_name = item_js_name; // every time you execute code within the module, update the global variable
   return processData(data);
}
```

inside some other module called FunStuff.mjs

```
const funstuff_js_name = 'FunStuff.mjs';

function doFunStuff() {
   global_js_name = funstuff_js_name; // update the global variable for the module
   return haveFun();
}
```

I'm not saying this is the best way to accomplish this task. Manually handling the changing of the global variable may be a pain.