# Extracting data with javascript for <script>?

Tags: javascript, json, typescript

I am trying to make a chrome extension and what I want to do is show the barcode number of the product on a shopping site in the extension. The data I want to show in the extension remains in `<script>`.

Namely using javascript.

```
<script type="application/javascript">
    window.__PRODUCT_DETAIL_APP_INITIAL_STATE__ = {"product":{"attributes":[],"alternativeVariants":[],"variants":[{"attributeId":0,"attributeName":"","attributeType":"","attributeValue":"","stamps":[{"type":1,"text":"KARGO BEDAVA"},{"type":3,"text":"%35"}],"price":{"profitMargin":4,"discountedPrice":{"text":"12,90 TL","value":12.9},"sellingPrice":{"text":"12,90 TL","value":12.9},"originalPrice":{"text":"19,90 TL","value":19.9},"currency":"TRY"},"attributeBeautifiedValue":"","isWinner":true,"listingId":"c2d72798d0f2c5503304cd3065bd63df","stock":null,"sellable":true,"availableForClaim":true,"barcode":"7400000422307","itemNumber":13663077}],"otherMerchants":[{"url":"/modacar/modacar-torpido-uzerine-kaydirmaz-nano-ped-422307-p-2851160?boutiqueId=316783&merchantId=119502","promotions":[],"isSellable":true,"isBasketDiscount":false,"hasStock":true,"price":{"profitMargin":4,"discountedPrice":{"text":"12,90 TL","value":12.9},"sellingPrice":{"text":"12,90 TL","value":12.9},"originalPrice":{"text":"14,90 TL","value":14.9},"currency":"TRY"},"merchant":{"id":119502,"name":"Buda Bizde","officialName":"HAMDİ ÖZKAN","cityName":" İstanbul ","taxNumber":"18377272210","sellerScore":9.2},"isFreeCargo":true,"deliveryInformation":{"isRushDelivery":false,"deliveryDate":"27 - 30 Ocak"}},{"url":"/modacar/modacar-torpido-uzerine-kaydirmaz-nano-ped-422307-p-2851160?boutiqueId=316783&merchantId=123255","promotions":[],"isSellable":true,"isBasketDiscount":false,"hasStock":true,"price":{"profitMargin":4,"discountedPrice":{"text":"12,95 TL","value":12.95},"sellingPrice":{"text":"12,95 TL","value":12.95},"originalPrice":{"text":"35,00 TL","value":35},"currency":"TRY"},"merchant":{"id":123255,"name":"MasterCar","officialName":"HAFİ ÇAĞLAR","cityName":" İstanbul ","taxNumber":"21637272516","sellerScore":9.3},"isFreeCargo":true,"deliveryInformation":{"isRushDelivery":false,"deliveryDate":"27 - 30 Ocak"}},{"url":"/modacar/modacar-torpido-uzerine-kaydirmaz-nano-ped-422307-p-2851160?boutiqueId=316783&merchantId=107808","promotions":[],"isSellable":true,"isBasketDiscount":false,"hasStock":true,"price":{"profitMargin":3,"discountedPrice":{"text":"14,90 TL","value":14.9},"sellingPrice":{"text":"14,90 TL","value":14.9},"originalPrice":{"text":"17,88 TL","value":17.88},"currency":"TRY"},"merchant":{"id":107808,"name":"Tvet","officialName":"TVET E-TİCARET KUYUM. ÇEYİZ ARACILIK VE KİR.S.VE TİC.LTD.ŞTİ.","cityName":" Zonguldak ","taxNumber":"8590632439","sellerScore":9.5},"isFreeCargo":true,"deliveryInformation":{"isRushDelivery":false,"deliveryDate":"27 - 30 Ocak"}},{"url":"/modacar/modacar-torpido-uzerine-kaydirmaz-nano-ped-422307-p-2851160?boutiqueId=316783&merchantId=106278","promotions":[],"isSellable":true,"isBasketDiscount":false,"hasStock":true,"price":{"profitMargin":3,"discountedPrice":{"text":"16,37 TL","value":16.37},"sellingPrice":{"text":"16,37 TL","value":16.37},"originalPrice":{"text":"32,73 TL","value":32.73},"currency":"TRY"},"merchant":{"id":106278,"name":"hesaplisepet","officialName":"RAMAZAN ULU","cityName":" İstanbul ","taxNumber":"39095129198","sellerScore":9},"isFreeCargo":true,"deliveryInformation":{"isRushDelivery":false,"deliveryDate":"27 - 30 Ocak"}},{"url":"/modacar/modacar-torpido-uzerine-kaydirmaz-nano-ped-422307-p-2851160?boutiqueId=316783&merchantId=118092","promotions":[],"isSellable":true,"isBasketDiscount":false,"hasStock":true,"price":{"profitMargin":4,"discountedPrice":{"text":"16,80 TL","value":16.8},"sellingPrice":{"text":"16,80 TL","value":16.8},"originalPrice":{"text":"30,55 TL","value":30.55},"currency":"TRY"},"merchant":{"id":118092,"name":"E-Marketing","officialName":"BELGÜZAR TEKERBAŞ","cityName":" İzmir ","taxNumber":"34100334154","sellerScore":8.7},"isFreeCargo":true,"deliveryInformation":{"isRushDelivery":false,"deliveryDate":"27 - 30 Ocak"}}],"campaign":{"id":316783,"name":"Oto Aksesuar","startDate":"2019-06-18T13:00:00","endDate":"2026-01-01T00:00:00","isMultipleSupplied":false,"stockTypeId":7,"url":"/oto-aksesuar/butikdetay/316783","showTimer":false},"category":{"id":103874,"name":"Torpido Aksesuarları","hierarchy":"Yaşam/Otomobil & Motosiklet/Otomobil/Araç İçi Aksesuarı/Torpido Aksesuarları","beautifiedName":"torpido-aksesuarlari"},"brand":{"id":102602,"name":"ModaCar","beautifiedName":"modacar","isVirtual":true},"color":"Karışık,Çok Renkli","showVariants":false,"id":2851160,"productCode":"7400000422307","name":"ModaCar Torpido Üzerine Kaydırmaz Nano Ped 422307 7400000422307","description":"\u003cul>\u003cli>Nano Pad ? Nano Pad(Pano,Buzdolabı,Fayans,Cam,Tahta,Pencere,Düzgün Duvar Gibi) Herhangi Bir Dikey Veya Yatay Düz Zemine Yapışır Ve Nesneleri Yerinde Tutar.Dünya Da Rakipsiz Nano Teknolojik Milyarlarca Nano Vakumlardan Oluşan Benzersiz Yüzey 90 Derecede Dahi Nesneleri Tutabilme Özelliğiürün Özellikleri : 13 X 7 Cmtüm Zeminlerde 90 Derece Dik Konumda Dahi Kullanabilmecep Telefonu,Gözlük,Kalem,Uzaktan Kumanda Cihazı,Anahtar,Demir Para Gibi Nesneleri Sabitleyebilmeyapıştığı Hiçbir Zeminde Herhangi Bir Iz Bırakmaz.Gücünü Kaybetmeye Başlayabilir – Suda Yıkayın Eski Haline Döneüzerine Koyacağınız Her Materyal,Kesinlikle Kaymaz.\u003c/li>\u003cli>Bu butikte indirim kuponları/kodları geçerli değildir.\u003c/li>\u003cli>Kampanya fiyatından satılmak üzere 10 adetten fazla stok sunulmuştur.\u003c/li>\u003cli>Ürün kartında gösterilen üstü çizili ilk fiyat tedarikçi tarafından beslenen perakende satış fiyatıdır.\u003c/li>\u003c/ul>","productGroupId":2304830,"tax":18,"businessUnit":"Oto Aksesuar","gender":{"name":"Unisex","id":3},"url":"/modacar/modacar-torpido-uzerine-kaydirmaz-nano-ped-422307-p-2851160","images":["/assets/product/media/images/20191017/19/437057/13663077/1/1_org_zoom.jpg"],"isSellable":true,"isBasketDiscount":false,"hasStock":true,"price":{"profitMargin":4,"discountedPrice":{"text":"12,90 TL","value":12.9},"sellingPrice":{"text":"12,90 TL","value":12.9},"originalPrice":{"text":"19,90 TL","value":19.9},"currency":"TRY"},"isFreeCargo":true,"promotions":[],"merchant":{"id":126041,"name":"Sincap Dükkan","officialName":"HALİT UZAN","cityName":" İstanbul ","taxNumber":"32711387002","sellerScore":9.2},"deliveryInformation":{"isRushDelivery":false,"deliveryDate":"27 - 30 Ocak"},"isMarketplace":true,"productStamps":[],"hasHtmlContent":false,"favoriteCount":581,"uxLayout":"General Merchandise"},"reviews":{"contentSummary":{"ratingCounts":[{"rate":1,"count":8},{"rate":2,"count":1},{"rate":3,"count":5},{"rate":4,"count":2},{"rate":5,"count":8}],"userCommentExist":false,"averageRating":3.04,"totalCommentCount":16,"totalRatingCount":24},"productReviews":{"totalElements":16,"totalPages":6,"page":0,"size":3,"content":[{"userFullName":"**** ****","commentDateISOtype":"2019-12-01","id":12283614,"rate":5,"commentTitle":"","comment":"Gayet güzel ben beğendim fiyatı da iyi malzeme de şyi","trusted":true,"lastModifiedDate":"1 Aralık 2019"},{"userFullName":"simge dikici","commentDateISOtype":"2019-07-31","id":3267976,"rate":5,"commentTitle":"","comment":"Telefonu gerçekten araçta kaydırmıyor. Kullanışlı bir ürün.","trusted":true,"lastModifiedDate":"31 Temmuz 2019"},{"userFullName":"**** ****","commentDateISOtype":"2019-11-14","id":8705641,"rate":5,"commentTitle":"","comment":"Çok kaliteli ve güzel","trusted":true,"lastModifiedDate":"14 Kasım 2019"}],"userCommentExist":false},"productSummary":null},"htmlContent":null,"user":{"loggedIn":false,"id":0,"isBuyer":false},"configuration":{"htmlContentCssUrl":"https://static.dsmcdn.com/frontend/pim/rich-content/production/main.cf9ab001241f21c7ffef520f9487ab4d.css","htmlContentJsUrl":"https://static.dsmcdn.com/frontend/pim/rich-content/production/main.8050003e34b702b545d67ec9d05bf408.js","storefrontId":1,"culture":"tr-TR","cdnUrl":"https://img-trendyol.mncdn.com","claimInfoText":"15 gün içinde ücretsiz iade.","ratingReviewEnabled":true,"ratingReviewLikesEnabled":true,"newRatingSummaryEnabled":false,"redirectReviewsPageEnabled":false,"languageCode":"tr","sizeCharts":[["Güneş Gözlüğü","https://img-trendyol.mncdn.com/assets/banner/2018/webBanners/bedenTablosu/gozluk_beden_tablosu.jpg","Gözlük Beden Kılavuzu"],["İmaj Gözlükleri","https://img-trendyol.mncdn.com/assets/banner/2018/webBanners/bedenTablosu/gozluk_beden_tablosu.jpg","Gözlük Beden Kılavuzu"],["Saat","https://img-trendyol.mncdn.com/assets/banner/2018/webBanners/bedenTablosu/saatler_beden_tablosu.jpg","Saat Beden Kılavuzu"]],"enhancedEcommerceEnabled":true,"addReviewEnabled":true,"reviewReportAbuseEnabled":true,"crossProductsTitle":"Bu Ürünü Alanlar Bunları da Aldı","crossProductsEnabled":true,"recommendationEnabled":true,"productGroupEnabled":true,"htmlContentEnabled":true,"productAttributesEnabled":true,"sellerAreaEnabled":true,"sellerPointLowLimit":8,"sizeChartUrl":"https://img-trendyol.mncdn.com/Assets/frontend-web-sizechart/tr1.html","productDetailMetaDescription":"Trendyol.com sayesinde {0} ürününe çok özel indirimlerle sahip olabilecek ve alışveriş alışkanlıklarınızı değiştireceksiniz.","schemaJsonEnabled":true,"siteAddress":"https://www.trendyol.com","notifyMeEnabled":true,"notifyMeCount":10,"accountGwFavoritesEnabled":true,"browsingGwUrl":"https://api.trendyol.com/webbrowsinggw","recommendationAbTestValue":"A_0-0,B_1-100,C_0-0","lastProductCountAbTestValue":"A_0-50,B_51-100","recoCardAbTestValue":"A_0-100,B_0-0","abTestingCookieName":"WebAbTesting","clientSideReviewsEnabled":false,"clientSideHtmlContentEnabled":false,"alternativeVariantsEnabled":true,"relatedCategoryEnabled":true,"relatedCategoryAbTestVariant":"C","relatedCategoryAbTestValue":"A_0-0,B_0-0,C_0-0,D_1-100,E_0-0","relatedCategoryTitleTooltipThreshold":30}};
  </script>
```

I want to pull the 7400000422307 data from the "barcode": "7400000422307" section in these codes, print it to the extension and copy it easily with a button.

**document.getElemtsByClassName, document.getElementById** I know that div = "class" or "div = id" is used, but I don't know what encoding is used for script. Can you help me.

Comment: maybe I am not reading this correctly, but why would you need to use a selector when it is set on the window? Just check for the existence of the `__PRODUCT_DETAIL_APP_INITIAL_STATE__` on the window and select the appropriate property on this object to get your barcode.

Answer (score 0):

For your case use:

```
document.querySelector('script[type="application/javascript"]')
```

for reference you can use this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/22745553/4103661

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the bar-code is the same as product code . Look at the bottom of the snippet to work out how I traversed it .

if you use

`console.log(window.__PRODUCT_DETAIL_APP_INITIAL_STATE__);`

at the bottom of your script its going to give you a long complex list of nested JSON data ...

If you need to work through it use a json Tree Viewer found here 
[JSON VIEWER](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/)

```js
window.__PRODUCT_DETAIL_APP_INITIAL_STATE__ = {
  "product": {
    "attributes": [],
    "alternativeVariants": [],
    "variants": [{
      "attributeId": 0,
      "attributeName": "",
      "attributeType": "",
      "attributeValue": "",
      "stamps": [{
        "type": 1,
        "text": "KARGO BEDAVA"
      }, {
        "type": 3,
        "text": "%35"
      }],
      "price": {
        "profitMargin": 4,
        "discountedPrice": {
          "text": "12,90 TL",
          "value": 12.9
        },
        "sellingPrice": {
          "text": "12,90 TL",
          "value": 12.9
        },
        "originalPrice": {
          "text": "19,90 TL",
          "value": 19.9
        },
        "currency": "TRY"
      },
      "attributeBeautifiedValue": "",
      "isWinner": true,
      "listingId": "c2d72798d0f2c5503304cd3065bd63df",
      "stock": null,
      "sellable": true,
      "availableForClaim": true,
      "barcode": "7400000422307",
      "itemNumber": 13663077
    }],
    "otherMerchants": [{
      "url": "/modacar/modacar-torpido-uzerine-kaydirmaz-nano-ped-422307-p-2851160?boutiqueId=316783&merchantId=119502",
      "promotions": [],
      "isSellable": true,
      "isBasketDiscount": false,
      "hasStock": true,
      "price": {
        "profitMargin": 4,
        "discountedPrice": {
          "text": "12,90 TL",
          "value": 12.9
        },
        "sellingPrice": {
          "text": "12,90 TL",
          "value": 12.9
        },
        "originalPrice": {
          "text": "14,90 TL",
          "value": 14.9
        },
        "currency": "TRY"
      },
      "merchant": {
        "id": 119502,
        "name": "Buda Bizde",
        "officialName": "HAMDİ ÖZKAN",
        "cityName": " İstanbul ",
        "taxNumber": "18377272210",
        "sellerScore": 9.2
      },
      "isFreeCargo": true,
      "deliveryInformation": {
        "isRushDelivery": false,
        "deliveryDate": "27 - 30 Ocak"
      }
    }, {
      "url": "/modacar/modacar-torpido-uzerine-kaydirmaz-nano-ped-422307-p-2851160?boutiqueId=316783&merchantId=123255",
      "promotions": [],
      "isSellable": true,
      "isBasketDiscount": false,
      "hasStock": true,
      "price": {
        "profitMargin": 4,
        "discountedPrice": {
          "text": "12,95 TL",
          "value": 12.95
        },
        "sellingPrice": {
          "text": "12,95 TL",
          "value": 12.95
        },
        "originalPrice": {
          "text": "35,00 TL",
          "value": 35
        },
        "currency": "TRY"
      },
      "merchant": {
        "id": 123255,
        "name": "MasterCar",
        "officialName": "HAFİ ÇAĞLAR",
        "cityName": " İstanbul ",
        "taxNumber": "21637272516",
        "sellerScore": 9.3
      },
      "isFreeCargo": true,
      "deliveryInformation": {
        "isRushDelivery": false,
        "deliveryDate": "27 - 30 Ocak"
      }
    }, {
      "url": "/modacar/modacar-torpido-uzerine-kaydirmaz-nano-ped-422307-p-2851160?boutiqueId=316783&merchantId=107808",
      "promotions": [],
      "isSellable": true,
      "isBasketDiscount": false,
      "hasStock": true,
      "price": {
        "profitMargin": 3,
        "discountedPrice": {
          "text": "14,90 TL",
          "value": 14.9
        },
        "sellingPrice": {
          "text": "14,90 TL",
          "value": 14.9
        },
        "originalPrice": {
          "text": "17,88 TL",
          "value": 17.88
        },
        "currency": "TRY"
      },
      "merchant": {
        "id": 107808,
        "name": "Tvet",
        "officialName": "TVET E-TİCARET KUYUM. ÇEYİZ ARACILIK VE KİR.S.VE TİC.LTD.ŞTİ.",
        "cityName": " Zonguldak ",
        "taxNumber": "8590632439",
        "sellerScore": 9.5
      },
      "isFreeCargo": true,
      "deliveryInformation": {
        "isRushDelivery": false,
        "deliveryDate": "27 - 30 Ocak"
      }
    }, {
      "url": "/modacar/modacar-torpido-uzerine-kaydirmaz-nano-ped-422307-p-2851160?boutiqueId=316783&merchantId=106278",
      "promotions": [],
      "isSellable": true,
      "isBasketDiscount": false,
      "hasStock": true,
      "price": {
        "profitMargin": 3,
        "discountedPrice": {
          "text": "16,37 TL",
          "value": 16.37
        },
        "sellingPrice": {
          "text": "16,37 TL",
          "value": 16.37
        },
        "originalPrice": {
          "text": "32,73 TL",
          "value": 32.73
        },
        "currency": "TRY"
      },
      "merchant": {
        "id": 106278,
        "name": "hesaplisepet",
        "officialName": "RAMAZAN ULU",
        "cityName": " İstanbul ",
        "taxNumber": "39095129198",
        "sellerScore": 9
      },
      "isFreeCargo": true,
      "deliveryInformation": {
        "isRushDelivery": false,
        "deliveryDate": "27 - 30 Ocak"
      }
    }, {
      "url": "/modacar/modacar-torpido-uzerine-kaydirmaz-nano-ped-422307-p-2851160?boutiqueId=316783&merchantId=118092",
      "promotions": [],
      "isSellable": true,
      "isBasketDiscount": false,
      "hasStock": true,
      "price": {
        "profitMargin": 4,
        "discountedPrice": {
          "text": "16,80 TL",
          "value": 16.8
        },
        "sellingPrice": {
          "text": "16,80 TL",
          "value": 16.8
        },
        "originalPrice": {
          "text": "30,55 TL",
          "value": 30.55
        },
        "currency": "TRY"
      },
      "merchant": {
        "id": 118092,
        "name": "E-Marketing",
        "officialName": "BELGÜZAR TEKERBAŞ",
        "cityName": " İzmir ",
        "taxNumber": "34100334154",
        "sellerScore": 8.7
      },
      "isFreeCargo": true,
      "deliveryInformation": {
        "isRushDelivery": false,
        "deliveryDate": "27 - 30 Ocak"
      }
    }],
    "campaign": {
      "id": 316783,
      "name": "Oto Aksesuar",
      "startDate": "2019-06-18T13:00:00",
      "endDate": "2026-01-01T00:00:00",
      "isMultipleSupplied": false,
      "stockTypeId": 7,
      "url": "/oto-aksesuar/butikdetay/316783",
      "showTimer": false
    },
    "category": {
      "id": 103874,
      "name": "Torpido Aksesuarları",
      "hierarchy": "Yaşam/Otomobil & Motosiklet/Otomobil/Araç İçi Aksesuarı/Torpido Aksesuarları",
      "beautifiedName": "torpido-aksesuarlari"
    },
    "brand": {
      "id": 102602,
      "name": "ModaCar",
      "beautifiedName": "modacar",
      "isVirtual": true
    },
    "color": "Karışık,Çok Renkli",
    "showVariants": false,
    "id": 2851160,
    "productCode": "7400000422307",
    "name": "ModaCar Torpido Üzerine Kaydırmaz Nano Ped 422307 7400000422307",
    "description": "\u003cul>\u003cli>Nano Pad ? Nano Pad(Pano,Buzdolabı,Fayans,Cam,Tahta,Pencere,Düzgün Duvar Gibi) Herhangi Bir Dikey Veya Yatay Düz Zemine Yapışır Ve Nesneleri Yerinde Tutar.Dünya Da Rakipsiz Nano Teknolojik Milyarlarca Nano Vakumlardan Oluşan Benzersiz Yüzey 90 Derecede Dahi Nesneleri Tutabilme Özelliğiürün Özellikleri : 13 X 7 Cmtüm Zeminlerde 90 Derece Dik Konumda Dahi Kullanabilmecep Telefonu,Gözlük,Kalem,Uzaktan Kumanda Cihazı,Anahtar,Demir Para Gibi Nesneleri Sabitleyebilmeyapıştığı Hiçbir Zeminde Herhangi Bir Iz Bırakmaz.Gücünü Kaybetmeye Başlayabilir – Suda Yıkayın Eski Haline Döneüzerine Koyacağınız Her Materyal,Kesinlikle Kaymaz.\u003c/li>\u003cli>Bu butikte indirim kuponları/kodları geçerli değildir.\u003c/li>\u003cli>Kampanya fiyatından satılmak üzere 10 adetten fazla stok sunulmuştur.\u003c/li>\u003cli>Ürün kartında gösterilen üstü çizili ilk fiyat tedarikçi tarafından beslenen perakende satış fiyatıdır.\u003c/li>\u003c/ul>",
    "productGroupId": 2304830,
    "tax": 18,
    "businessUnit": "Oto Aksesuar",
    "gender": {
      "name": "Unisex",
      "id": 3
    },
    "url": "/modacar/modacar-torpido-uzerine-kaydirmaz-nano-ped-422307-p-2851160",
    "images": ["/assets/product/media/images/20191017/19/437057/13663077/1/1_org_zoom.jpg"],
    "isSellable": true,
    "isBasketDiscount": false,
    "hasStock": true,
    "price": {
      "profitMargin": 4,
      "discountedPrice": {
        "text": "12,90 TL",
        "value": 12.9
      },
      "sellingPrice": {
        "text": "12,90 TL",
        "value": 12.9
      },
      "originalPrice": {
        "text": "19,90 TL",
        "value": 19.9
      },
      "currency": "TRY"
    },
    "isFreeCargo": true,
    "promotions": [],
    "merchant": {
      "id": 126041,
      "name": "Sincap Dükkan",
      "officialName": "HALİT UZAN",
      "cityName": " İstanbul ",
      "taxNumber": "32711387002",
      "sellerScore": 9.2
    },
    "deliveryInformation": {
      "isRushDelivery": false,
      "deliveryDate": "27 - 30 Ocak"
    },
    "isMarketplace": true,
    "productStamps": [],
    "hasHtmlContent": false,
    "favoriteCount": 581,
    "uxLayout": "General Merchandise"
  },
  "reviews": {
    "contentSummary": {
      "ratingCounts": [{
        "rate": 1,
        "count": 8
      }, {
        "rate": 2,
        "count": 1
      }, {
        "rate": 3,
        "count": 5
      }, {
        "rate": 4,
        "count": 2
      }, {
        "rate": 5,
        "count": 8
      }],
      "userCommentExist": false,
      "averageRating": 3.04,
      "totalCommentCount": 16,
      "totalRatingCount": 24
    },
    "productReviews": {
      "totalElements": 16,
      "totalPages": 6,
      "page": 0,
      "size": 3,
      "content": [{
        "userFullName": "**** ****",
        "commentDateISOtype": "2019-12-01",
        "id": 12283614,
        "rate": 5,
        "commentTitle": "",
        "comment": "Gayet güzel ben beğendim fiyatı da iyi malzeme de şyi",
        "trusted": true,
        "lastModifiedDate": "1 Aralık 2019"
      }, {
        "userFullName": "simge dikici",
        "commentDateISOtype": "2019-07-31",
        "id": 3267976,
        "rate": 5,
        "commentTitle": "",
        "comment": "Telefonu gerçekten araçta kaydırmıyor. Kullanışlı bir ürün.",
        "trusted": true,
        "lastModifiedDate": "31 Temmuz 2019"
      }, {
        "userFullName": "**** ****",
        "commentDateISOtype": "2019-11-14",
        "id": 8705641,
        "rate": 5,
        "commentTitle": "",
        "comment": "Çok kaliteli ve güzel",
        "trusted": true,
        "lastModifiedDate": "14 Kasım 2019"
      }],
      "userCommentExist": false
    },
    "productSummary": null
  },
  "htmlContent": null,
  "user": {
    "loggedIn": false,
    "id": 0,
    "isBuyer": false
  },
  "configuration": {
    "htmlContentCssUrl": "https://static.dsmcdn.com/frontend/pim/rich-content/production/main.cf9ab001241f21c7ffef520f9487ab4d.css",
    "htmlContentJsUrl": "https://static.dsmcdn.com/frontend/pim/rich-content/production/main.8050003e34b702b545d67ec9d05bf408.js",
    "storefrontId": 1,
    "culture": "tr-TR",
    "cdnUrl": "https://img-trendyol.mncdn.com",
    "claimInfoText": "15 gün içinde ücretsiz iade.",
    "ratingReviewEnabled": true,
    "ratingReviewLikesEnabled": true,
    "newRatingSummaryEnabled": false,
    "redirectReviewsPageEnabled": false,
    "languageCode": "tr",
    "sizeCharts": [
      ["Güneş Gözlüğü", "https://img-trendyol.mncdn.com/assets/banner/2018/webBanners/bedenTablosu/gozluk_beden_tablosu.jpg", "Gözlük Beden Kılavuzu"],
      ["İmaj Gözlükleri", "https://img-trendyol.mncdn.com/assets/banner/2018/webBanners/bedenTablosu/gozluk_beden_tablosu.jpg", "Gözlük Beden Kılavuzu"],
      ["Saat", "https://img-trendyol.mncdn.com/assets/banner/2018/webBanners/bedenTablosu/saatler_beden_tablosu.jpg", "Saat Beden Kılavuzu"]
    ],
    "enhancedEcommerceEnabled": true,
    "addReviewEnabled": true,
    "reviewReportAbuseEnabled": true,
    "crossProductsTitle": "Bu Ürünü Alanlar Bunları da Aldı",
    "crossProductsEnabled": true,
    "recommendationEnabled": true,
    "productGroupEnabled": true,
    "htmlContentEnabled": true,
    "productAttributesEnabled": true,
    "sellerAreaEnabled": true,
    "sellerPointLowLimit": 8,
    "sizeChartUrl": "https://img-trendyol.mncdn.com/Assets/frontend-web-sizechart/tr1.html",
    "productDetailMetaDescription": "Trendyol.com sayesinde {0} ürününe çok özel indirimlerle sahip olabilecek ve alışveriş alışkanlıklarınızı değiştireceksiniz.",
    "schemaJsonEnabled": true,
    "siteAddress": "https://www.trendyol.com",
    "notifyMeEnabled": true,
    "notifyMeCount": 10,
    "accountGwFavoritesEnabled": true,
    "browsingGwUrl": "https://api.trendyol.com/webbrowsinggw",
    "recommendationAbTestValue": "A_0-0,B_1-100,C_0-0",
    "lastProductCountAbTestValue": "A_0-50,B_51-100",
    "recoCardAbTestValue": "A_0-100,B_0-0",
    "abTestingCookieName": "WebAbTesting",
    "clientSideReviewsEnabled": false,
    "clientSideHtmlContentEnabled": false,
    "alternativeVariantsEnabled": true,
    "relatedCategoryEnabled": true,
    "relatedCategoryAbTestVariant": "C",
    "relatedCategoryAbTestValue": "A_0-0,B_0-0,C_0-0,D_1-100,E_0-0",
    "relatedCategoryTitleTooltipThreshold": 30
  }
};

 console.log(window.__PRODUCT_DETAIL_APP_INITIAL_STATE__.product.productCode);
```