# javascript - get width of element without knowing the ID

Tags: javascript, width

I have the following code:

```
<div>
<script>
// get the width of the parent element
</script>
</div>
```

it is possibile to get the width (and the height) of the parent element **where the script tag is placed**?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How may I reference the script tag that loaded the currently-executing script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/403967/how-may-i-reference-the-script-tag-that-loaded-the-currently-executing-script)

Answer (score 4):

> **Important note:** the following solution is [not supported in IE](https://caniuse.com/?search=currentscript).

Yes, you can use [`document.currentScript`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/currentScript) to get a reference to the current script tag, and then use [`parentNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentNode):

```html
<div>
<script>
  const {width, height} = getComputedStyle(document.currentScript.parentNode);
  console.log({width, height});
</script>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow, [`document.currentScript`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/currentScript) is new to me.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementsByTagName("div").getBoundingClientRect().width
document.getElementsByTagName("div").getBoundingClientRect().height
```

Comment: That is not the div the script is in

Answer (score 0):

Try currentScript.closest

```html
<div>
  <h1>Content</h1>
  <script>
    const thisScript = document.currentScript;
    const container = thisScript.closest("div")
    const ch = container.clientHeight;
    const oh = container.offsetHeight;
    const sh = container.scrollHeight;
    const h = container.style.height || "not set";
    const gc = getComputedStyle(container)

    console.log(ch, oh, sh, h, gc.height)
  </script>
</div>
```