# parentElement returns undefined Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to set an attribute of "attribute" with the value of "value" on the Sprint link, why is the parentElement returning undefined?

```
<a> Sprint
    <script>  
      const value = "sprint-info"
      const target = this.parentElement;
      target.setAttribute("attribute", "value");
      console.log(target)
    </script>  
  </a>
```

Comment: ```this.parentNode``` also returns undefined

Comment: What do you expect `this` to refer to?

Comment: `this` would be the `window` object here.

Comment: I wanted it to select the <script> element

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/403967/how-may-i-reference-the-script-tag-that-loaded-the-currently-executing-script

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How may I reference the script tag that loaded the currently-executing script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/403967/how-may-i-reference-the-script-tag-that-loaded-the-currently-executing-script)

Comment: As for how the `this` works, see [How does the “this” keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<a> Sprint
    <script>  
      const value = "sprint-info"
      const target = document.currentScript.parentElement;
      target.setAttribute("attribute", "value");
      console.log(target)
    </script>  
  </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add an `id` to the `script` tag, and get the `parentElement` using `querySelector`.

```html
<a> Sprint
    <script id="myScript">  
      const value = "sprint-info"
      const target = document.querySelector("#myScript").parentElement;
      target.setAttribute("attribute", "value");
      console.log(target)
    </script>  
  </a>
```

Answer (score -1):

A script tag is not treated as a tradition DOM element, you're better of just using a querySelector

```
<a class="sprint"> Sprint </a>

<script>  
      const value = "sprint-info"
      const target = document.querySelector('.sprint');
      target.setAttribute("attribute", "value");
      console.log(target)
</script>
```

Comment: This solution does work, but does not directly answer the question. Also I believe the statement "A script tag is not treated as an HTML element" is incorrect.

Comment: A script tag is most definitely treated as an HTML element. An [`HTMLScriptElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLScriptElement) to be precise.

Comment: Sorry I guess I should have said "tradition DOM element" my bad, reading that again I can understand that could have caused confusion