# How do I get a parent element of script tag in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Suppose I have a script tag :
`<script src="https://example.com/test.js"></script>`
I want to insert this script tag inside other HTML tags like : `form`, `div`, `section` etc.
So If I insert script tag inside form tag :

```
<form>
  <script src="https://example.com/test.js"></script>
</form>
```

`https://example.com/test.js` should console the closest parent element, which is `form`.
Similarly, If we insert script tag inside a div, it should console the closest parent element which is `div` in this case.
Is there any way to achieve this ?

Comment: Dupe target + `.parentNode`/`.parentElement`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the script `test.js` you can use:

```js
scriptParent = document.currentScript.parentElement;
```

or you can use other solutions from [How may I reference the script tag that loaded the currently-executing script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/403967/how-may-i-reference-the-script-tag-that-loaded-the-currently-executing-script)
and add `.parentElement` to it.