# Hide current table row inline using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following html that I cannot modify. (It is being auto-generated)

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>UserName</th>
      <td>Bob</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Password</th>
      <td>Fred</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

This would display:

```
UserName  Bob
Password  Fred
```

However, I can insert code inside the td area.  I would like to hide the parent row using javascript or css.

**Example**

For example, if I wanted to hide the second row I can insert javascript:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>UserName</th>
      <td>Bob</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Password</th>
      <td>Fred <script type="text/javascript">document.parentrow.hide();</script> </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

And then it should just display

```
UserName  Bob
```

**Notes**

- The function document.parentrow.hide(); does not work but it is just to show an example of what I am looking for. I would like a function
  that hides the current row associated with that td.
- I cannot add custom class or id to the tr tags since I have no control over that portion of the html.
- I did take a look at the following link [How may I reference the script tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/403967/how-may-i-reference-the-script-tag-that-loaded-the-currently-executing-script) but it is just a general topic.  It does not have the answer to my question regarding table rows.

Answer (score 0):

It was very easy with the document closest tag as follows.  I just added this to the corresponding td tag:

```
<td>Fred
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var myscript = document.currentScript;
    var myrow = myscript.closest('tr');
    myrow.hidden = true;
  </script>
</td>
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>UserName</th>
      <td>Bob</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Password</th>
      <td>Fred
        <script type="text/javascript">
          var myscript = document.currentScript;
          var myrow = myscript.closest('tr');
          myrow.hidden = true;
        </script>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```